# Getting a json string request parameter

Tags: javascript, java, json, request

I have a json object and when it is passing through a request parameter on client side,and server side the json string is breaking from **space** character.

ex:

```
{"id":100,"age":15,"name":"sample string"}
```

when its come to the **request.getParameter()** showing like this

```
{"id":100,"age":15,"name":"sample
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var location='MyAction.do?method=myMethod';
var form = '<input type="hidden" name="transactionId" value="'+getSession()+'" /><input type="hidden" name="myInfo" value='+JSON.stringify(myInfo)+' />';
$('<form action="' + location + '" method="POST">' + form + '</form>').appendTo($(document.body)).submit();
```

**JAVA**

```
String myInfo = request.getParameter("myInfo");
```

This is only happening when info string having space characters.how can I get the full string?

thanks.

Comment: You should share some other details with us, such as server side framework and client side code as well

Comment: I've never faced like that.

Comment: Are you sure it's a space and not a new line? Can you control how the JSON string is being passed? If you're using the querystring parameters, you should URLencode your JSON string before adding to the URL

Comment: @jasonscript  yes I'm passing it as querystring.what do you mean by encoding.doing spaces to '%20'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can encode your values

```
value='+JSON.stringify(myInfo)+'
```

This will give the raw string with spaces etc. You can use the in-built `encodeURIComponent(string)` method to encode your string

```
var myInfo = {"id":100,"age":15,"name":"sample string"};
encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(myInfo));
```

this returns the encoded string. This doesn't contain any symbols that might confuse the browser (<kbd>{</kbd><kbd>}</kbd><kbd>[space]</kbd><kbd>&</kbd><kbd>?</kbd> etc)

> %7B%22id%22%3A100%2C%22age%22%3A15%2C%22name%22%3A%22sample%20string%22%7D

You can then decode it using `decodeURIComponent(string)`

```
var request_value = decodeURIComponent('%7B%22id%22%3A100%2C%22age%22%3A15%2C%22name%22%3A%22sample%20string%22%7D');
JSON.parse(request_value);
```